# draw petri net graph of Travelling salesman

Tags: modeling, traveling-salesman, petri-net

Can you draw the petri net model of Travelling salesman problem?
Is it possible in petri net to have places with different kinds?

Comment: Regarding your second question, there are multiple extensions of the Petri net model that support places with different kinds. One of the most popular would be Colored Petri nets that permit differentiating places, arcs and individual tokens. As for the first question it is not clear what you are asking: try to think of an illustrative example.

Comment: @Dmitri Chubarov thanks, In the classic petri net(not colored,..) Is it possible to have places with different kind?for example one place is kind of action an another is object? for first question I want to have only petri net graph for Travelling salesman problem? Do you say that I explain the Travelling salesman problem?

Comment: The TSP is a problem usually stated for graphs with weighted arcs. A Petri net graph is a bipartite oriented graph with two separate sets of vertices: places and transitions. You want a Petri net for every instance of TSP. It's not clear to me, what meaning would you give to places and transitions of such a Petri net, how would you encode the cost of a route into a Petri net. This sounds like a strange idea to me.

Comment: @Dmitri Chubarov Thank you very much indeed, therefore petri net is not very suitable for TSP